# How to randomize "X" and "O" symbols for the first player in a Tic-Tac-Toe game using a default parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, module, socket.io

In the Node.js module - GameModule.js, which exports a class called "Game" and describes the game state, the starting player is not static, it should be set during the instantiation of a Game-Object.

So the starting player should be randomly set to "X" or "O" on each begin of the Game using the default parameter in a Constructor.

It is a simple Tic-tac-toe game, which allows to play a game between two users in two different browsers.

I can assign the starting player in server.js to be "X" or "O" but cannot figure out how to randomize this in a Game Module using the default parameter in a Constructor.

Here is a part of GameModule.js, where firstPlayer value need to be randomly assigned to "X" or "O":

```
    class Game {
      constructor(el = "X") {
        this.firstPlayer = el;
        this.currentPlayer = "";
        this.gameField = [
          ["", "", ""],
          ["", "", ""],
          ["", "", ""]
        ];
        this.result = "";
      }
    }
```

And here is the part of server.js that instantiate a Game-Object:

```
    let gameModule = require("./GameModule.js");
    let myGame = new gameModule.Game();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). It gives a random number between `0` and `1` and since we want `X` and `O` to be [equiprobable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equiprobability) we can mark the threshold at 0.5:

```
this.firstPlayer = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "X" : "O";
```

Demo:

```js
const randomPlayer = () => Math.random() > 0.5 ? "X" : "O";

for(let i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
  console.log(randomPlayer());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.random to generate a random number, then assign x or o with a 50% chance each

```
class Game {
  constructor() {
    this.firstPlayer = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.currentPlayer = "";
    this.gameField = [
      ["", "", ""],
      ["", "", ""],
      ["", "", ""]
    ];
    this.result = "";
  }
}
```